# My Shopify app replaces the product form - option_selection.js breaks: can't access its "parentNode" property

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

My Shopify app replaces the product pages 'Add To Cart' form / product form, with it's own form of sorts. It is Liquid logic that decides whether or not to render the entire `<form>` element.

This works great, but on some themes (like Jumpstart by Shopify), the product page bugs out completely, throwing me an error saying:

`option_selection.js - can't access its "parentNode" property`

Which I believe is the option_selection.js function where it is looking for the select box / variant ID somewhere on the page.

Of course, this variant ID / select box does not exist because it is not being rendered.

How can I replace the add to cart form while satisfying the option_selection.js functions?

Usually this wouldn't be a big deal, but Shopify's app review team will give me problems with this, and on the Jumpstart theme specifically, this error causes the product photos to not render; breaking the page completely.

Any ideas here? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axing the entire product form seems a bit extreme - there's no way to do what you need to do in a less invasive way?

Assuming not, you'll want to expand your install so that you can update any code in a theme that initializes the product form to take into account the possibility that you've defied the theme's simplistic assumptions.

For the option_selection.js compatibility, you'll be looking for where `new Shopify.OptionSelectors` is being invoked. If your code has set a variable through Javascript, that may be the easiest check to make. Example of an inline install that assumes your code creates a function named MyAppNamespace.isProdHidden:

Original:

```
new Shopify.OptionSelectors( ...
```

Updated:

```
!(window.MyAppNamespace && MyAppNamespace.isProdHidden({{ product.id | json }}) ) && new Shopify.OptionSelectors( ...
```

The added piece of code will evaluate to `false` if and only if your app has loaded properly and your `isProdHidden` function returns a truthy value. This scenario would prevent the `new Shopify.OptionSelectors` part from running, since we're using the `&&` as a sort of short-circuit/emergency-stop operation.

If your app failed to load (or was uninstalled from the store without the liquid code being updated), or if `MyAppNamespace.isProdHidden` returns `false`, then the added block of code evaluates as `true` and the `new Shopify.OptionSelectors` happens as normal.

The above is equivalent to wrapping the entire `new Shopify.OptionSelectors` call in an `if` statement, with the install benefit that the party installing your app doesn't need to read the theme code to figure out where the `OptionSelectors` call ends.  In most themes the `OptionSelectors` code is spread out over multiple lines and occasionally theme developers declare their `onVariantChange` function as an inline anonymous function - neither of which are big obstacles for experienced developers, but a huge complication for novices and store owners without this kind of expertise.

Making the status of your app available somehow through Javascript is probably the best thing for you to do as far as theme-install-compatibility goes.  Some themes have their `OptionSelectors` call right in the product page, which can be affected by dynamic Liquid variables, but many have this code tucked away in a .js file in the assets folder instead. Still other themes don't use Shopify's `OptionSelectors` code at all and instead run their own thing, and thus your app could interfere in completely unexpected ways or places.  Creating tools to make it easier to integrate your app into somebody else's code is therefore one of the best things you can do.

You'll also want to make sure that your code is able to handle multiple products, as many stores have quick-shops all through the site which can load arbitrary product forms. By making sure you have made the tools available, it's possible for you, your support team (if any) and theme devs can make the required updates to (almost!) any arbitrary theme.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks so much Dave. Very in depth! 
Maybe I'll have to look into alternative options instead of replacing the entire form... The issue is my app doesn't differentiate between variants, so it would be confusing for users to see the select box for variants, click my app button, but the variant they selected not triggered within my app. 
That's why I did 'replace the whole form'.

Comment: I've decided to do the CSS hide route, I'm able to just wrap the product form in a div that I can hide/display depending on my app's setting. Works just as good, hopefully don't encounter any other hiccups!

Thanks so much for your answer though Dave, appreciate it. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution that works!  Good luck with your app listing!